# Bootstrap 3 Tabs - Show on Hover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to make my tabs activate on hover. What's the best way to make that happen? Ideally without changing the tabs.js file.

Here's my url http://opennetsummit.wpengine.com/

The tabs are the three image options in the middle of the page.

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <!-- Tabs -->
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav panel-tabs">
                <li class="active col-sm-3">
                    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
                        <div>
                            <img src="http://opennetsummit.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ons-rocket-icon.png">
                            <h3>Workshops</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
                        <div>
                            <img src="http://opennetsummit.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ons-circles-icon.png">
                            <h3>Open Networking Summit</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
                        <div>
                            <img src="http://opennetsummit.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ons-inspire-icon.png">
                            <h3>Webinars</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="mid-form">
                        <h3>Get Updates</h3>
                        <form method="post" action="http://opennetsummit.wpengine.com/" id="mc4wp-form-1" class="form mc4wp-form form-inline" _lpchecked="1">
                            <div class="row mid-form">

                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="First Name" required="required" class="form-control" style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" name="LNAME" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address" required="required" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <textarea name="_mc4wp_required_but_not_really" style="display: none !important;" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_form_submit" value="1" class="form-control">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_form_instance" value="1" class="form-control">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_mc4wp_form_nonce" value="d8732ddff8" class="form-control">
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body hompage-panel">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 active" id="tab1">
                <div class="col-sm-4 center">
                    <img src="http://opennetsummit.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ons-circles-middle.png">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <h2>Defy Protocol </h2>
                    <h1>EMBRACE {OPEN} SOFTWARE</h1>
                    <h3>Open Networking Summit</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <p>June 15 - 18, 2015</p>
                    <p>Santa Clara Convention Center</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-more">More Information</a>       
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="tab2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="tab3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is $(...).hover(function(){//open tab} an option?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to alter the tabs.js

You just need to call the action like Steve suggested in the comments. There are examples here for basic showing. 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

You just need to attach it to hover  - http://api.jquery.com/hover/